# Invoking GraphQL endpoints from curl failing unexpectedly

Tags: bash, curl, graphql

I've been using REST APIs (both as a consumer and a developer of) for many years and am just starting to work with a GraphQL API for the first time, specifically, [BurpSuite's Enterprise GraphQL API](https://portswigger.net/burp/extensibility/enterprise/graphql-api/). I like it but I'm definitely missing a few critical concepts.

I am trying to hit their [`GetScan`](https://portswigger.net/burp/extensibility/enterprise/graphql-api/Scan.html) endpoint:

```sh
curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: <MY_API_KEY>" -X GET -d '{ "query": "query GetScan ($id: ID!) { scan(id: $id) { id status agent { id name } site_application_logins { login_credentials { label username } recorded_logins { label } } audit_items { id issue_counts { total } number_of_requests } scan_configurations { id name } } }"}' 'https://mybsee.example.com/graphql/v1'
```

For easier reading, that graphql query is also:

```
query GetScan ($id: ID!) {
  scan(id: $id) {
    id status
    agent { id name }
    site_application_logins {
      login_credentials { label username }
      recorded_logins { label }
    }
    audit_items {
      id
      issue_counts { total }
      number_of_requests
    }
    scan_configurations { id name }
  }
},
variables {
    $agent: "Firefox"
}
```

Above `<MY_API_KEY>` has a real value when I run it (I can't post it here, obviously). Same with the URL (I have an on-premise version of BurpSuite running off, say, `mybsee.example.com`).

When I run that curl, I get the following output:

```
About to execute: query GetScan ($id: ID!) { scan(id: $id) { id status agent { id name } site_application_logins { login_credentials { label username } recorded_logins { label } } audit_items { id issue_counts { total } number_of_requests } scan_configurations { id name } } }
HTTP/2 200 
date: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 23:33:50 GMT
x-frame-options: DENY
<lots of response headers omitted>

{"errors":[{"message":"Unexpected exception occurred. Check logs for more details.","extensions":{"code":77}}]}
```

I don't have access to the server logs, so I'm trying to rule out an issue on the client-side (bad call to `GetScan` on my part). Anything look wrong to anybody? Should I be injecting values to any of the fields in the query, such as `id` or `status`, etc.? If so, how (specifically) could I change the query to be valid? I'm also not sure if I need to append a `"query"` JSON field name into the actual query or not.

Thanks for any and all help here.

#### Update

I do realize that this is not a *perfectly* answerable problem, because the BurpSuite API is unfortunately proprietary and you cannot obtain an API key from them unless you purchase the product or go through a lot of rigamarole to get a free trial license.

But more importantly, I'm not looking for anyone to fish for me here, I'm hoping someone can teach me *how* to fish. In reality I need to integrate with a lot more GraphQL endpoints besides this one, but if someone can show me the proper way to construct one query, I can take it from there.

Comment: You are missnig a double quote at the end of `-H "Authorization:`... for one thing.

Comment: Thanks @chicks (+1) that was a copy-n-paste error on my end; fixed now!

Comment: I don't see any variables in your query. Where are you passing the specific id?

Comment: (btw, formatting the graphql query as multi-line properly indented text would make it a lot easier to read).

Comment: ...that said, the bigger issue here is that we have a question with no [mre]; nobody but you (or another BurpScan customer with a valid API key) can reproduce your problem, so testing an answer one might want to submit or concretely determining whether someone else's answer is correct isn't possible without spending money.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy (+1) how and where do you see variables in the query above? For instances, lets say one of the variables is "`agent`" (I'm not saying it is, just using it as an example). Let's say I want to pass the string "Firefox" as a value for the `agent` variable...how would I do that? Thanks again!

Comment: `"query"` is one section. `"variables"` is another. If your query refers to variables (as opposed to inlining them, which is also an option), you make your data look like `{"query": "...$myVariable...", "variables": { "myVariable": "data here"}}` -- note the big "if" in that because right now your query is provided as a one liner with no formatting/indentation making it too much trouble to read for details.

Comment: Basically, though: `GetScan` needs to be given an `id` as a parameter -- the `!` in `ID!` says it's mandatory.

Comment: Ahhh thanks @CharlesDuffy, and thanks for the edit. I actually _just_ edited your edit to invlude my first pass at a `variables` section. Does that look right to you or am I still missing something "big picture"-wise? Thanks again for all the great help so far.

Comment: `variables` should be a separate piece of the JSON document, not part of the query. And you don't need the `$` in the name in the variable section. See my earlier comment: You've got `{"query": "...query here...", "variables": {"VALUES": "HERE}}` in the JSON you actually send the server; so the `query` section stays constant and only the `variables` section changes when you parameterize your specific call.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, please see my final update above. I'm getting the _gist_ of what you're saying but it would be helpful if you or anyone else could show me a "full", valid example, with a query that injects dummy values into the query variables. I think that would lock it in for me. I realize its not a reproducible problem because its a proprietary API, but I actually don't see any good working examples out there showing variable injection into the query. So even an answer that shows proper variable injection would probably be of immense value not only to myself but others. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to do this is to use `jq` to generate correctly-escaped JSON with both your query and its parameters.

Building a function to automate that:

```
# usage: gqlQuery http://ENDPOINT/graphql "$query" arg1=val1 arg2=val2 ...
gqlQuery() {
  local endpoint query postBody
  local -a jqArgs=( )
  endpoint=$1; shift || return
  query=$1; shift || return
  while (( $# )); do
    case $1 in

      # the variable name "query" is used for passing in, well, the query
      query=*)  echo "ERROR: variable name query is reserved" >&2; return 1;;

      # 'foo=JSON:["bar", "baz"]' passes ["bar", "baz"] as a list, not a string
      *=JSON:*) jqArgs+=( --argjson "${1%%=*}" "${1#*=}" ) ;;

      # without JSON:, everything gets passed as a string to the child
      *=*)      jqArgs+=( --arg "${1%%=*}" "${1#*=}" ) ;;

      # arguments without a = are not recognized
      *)        echo "ERROR: Argument $1 not well-formed" >&2; return 1;;
    esac
    shift
  done
  postBody=$(jq -nc \
    --arg query "$query" \
    "${jqArgs[@]}" \
    '{ "query": $query, "variables": ($ARGS.named | del(.query)) }'
  ) || return
  curl --fail -XPOST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d "$postBody" "$endpoint"
}
```

...you might use such a function as:

```
getScanQuery='query GetScan ($id: ID!) { scan(id: $id) { id status agent { id name } site_application_logins { login_credentials { label username } recorded_logins { label } } audit_items { id issue_counts { total } number_of_requests } scan_configurations { id name } } }'
myUrl=https://mybsee.example.com/graphql/v1
scanIdToRetrieve=1000 # replace with whatever is appropriate

result=$(gqlQuery "$myUrl" "$getScanQuery" id="$scanIdToRetrieve")
```

Comment: Ahhhh ok, I think I'm getting it! So let's take the very first part of that `getScanQuery` variable: `GetScan ($id: ID!) { scan(id: $id)...`/ Does this translate as "there is a `GetScan` endpoint that takes a single **required** argument, `$id`, that is of type "ID" (I assume `ID` is a type in GQL-land)? And then everywhere `$id` is referenced in the query body, the value passed in from the `variables` map is substituted? Is that how it works? Also I assume its `gqlQuery` everywhere and not `golQuery`, right? Thanks again!

Comment: Quite right that `golQuery` was a typo, and also quite right that `ID` is a type (types can be defined as part of the query text when they aren't predefined; I don't offhand remember if `ID` is a predefined type or not -- if it isn't one, then you might need to include its definition inside the query body).

Comment: The only reason I'm a little hesitant to affirm the "everywhere $id is referenced in the body" bit is that the arguments to the `GetScan` query determine what's filled out in the references inside the block, but it's a distinction that doesn't really make much of a difference; the way you described it is pretty much close enough in general :)

Comment: Looking it up in https://graphql.org/learn/schema/, `ID` is indeed a predefined type.

Comment: BTW, the version of `gqlQuery` above was a quick one-off; if I were building something meant for production use I'd probably add something like `-X*) curlArgs+=( "${1%-X} );;` to the top of the `case` statement (after defining `local -a curlArgs=( )` at the top, and using `curl "${curlArgs[@]}"` at the bottom) to let callers pass extra arguments to `curl` without needing to change the function.

Comment: (heh: I just realized that would have looked like a really weird typo to anyone using QWERTY. My keyboard layout is dvorak, so "o" is just above "q").

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <API_TOKEN>" -X POST -d "{ \"query\": \"$string\"}" '<API_URL>'
```

You did almost everything right. Just Change the HTTP Method to POST instead of GET. GET will try to fetch the whole page, POST on the other hand will interact with the GraphQL API.

Nevertheless stated in the [GraphQL serving over HTTP page](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/) that GET Method should also work with queries under certain limtations. Refer the links for more Information.

Also consider visting other Webpages which lead me to this resolution;
[Introduction to GraphQL on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/introduction-to-graphql)
[Making GraphQL Requests using HTTP Methods](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/basics/making-graphql-requests-using-http-methods/)
[Burp Suite Enterprise GraphQL forum discussion with the same Error code of yours](https://forum.portswigger.net/thread/burp-suite-enterprise-graphql-2246c07f)

Comment: Thanks @Ido (+1), two followup questions if you don't mind: **(1)** is GraphQL **always** a POST, even for queries? If not, why do you suggest I use a POST here? And **(2)** do I need to inject variable values into my query? If so, how (specifically, with an example) could I accomplish that? Thanks again!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup, yes, it's always a POST, whether you're doing a query or a mutation.

Comment: Showcasing `curl -k` (`--insecure`) in an example others may follow without thinking about it is a _really_ bad idea. Beyond that, the OP's GraphQL query needs an `id` variable, but they aren't passing one.